# .htaccess has no effect

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I am loosing hours with this (should-be) simple task. I want to restrict access to my website, which is on my server in /var/www/.

I've created /etc/apache2/passwords file with httpasswd successfuly (user primoz). I've put .htaccess in /var/www/ and this is the content:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "RestrictedFiles"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
Require user primoz
```

My website is still accessible.
I also tried editing the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default - line *AllowOverride None* to *AllowOverride All*. No need to mention that it didn't make any changes.

Should restricting really be this frustrating?

**EDIT:**
*/etc/apache2/httpd.conf* is empty by default because I run server on Debian - which uses apache2.conf instead.

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1302921/) is the whole apache2.conf.

Comment: From the sounds of it, it seems that your `.htaccess` is just not enabled. Is this line: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` uncommented in your httpd.conf?

Comment: /etc/apache2/httpd.conf is empty and AFAIK is not used anymore by apache. Though I have tried enabling *rewrite* with *sudo a2enmod* but also this doesn't solve it :)

Comment: Are you closing your browser and re-opening before testing this auth each time?

Comment: No I didn't try that before. I tried it just now and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. The configuration in */etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default* had  *AllowOverride None* instead of *AllowOverride All*.

I was sure I changed this but I guess I reverted the file when it didn't work (don't remember why - probably something else was misconfigured). Anyways, the first paragraph is the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Enable .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "RestrictedFiles"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
Require valid-user
```

Also make sure mod_authn_core is enabled.

Comment: I am using Apache 2.2.* and httpd.conf is empty. Also, *authn_core* doesn't exist via *a2enmod*!

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at mine (which is in use):

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/www.site.com/htdocs/.htpasswd 
AuthName Password_secure
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

You should also edit your *`apache2.conf`* and make sure the following are enabled:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And the options/allows:

```
<Directory /your/path>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Satisfy all
</Directory>
```

If it's for a virtual host, then this block needs to sit within `<VirtualHost></VirtualHost>` tags.

Beyond these, It's difficult to see what causing you issues without looking at the full *`apache2.conf`*

Comment: I think my .htaccess is OK. It' just not enabled and I don't know how to enable it.

Comment: If I put *AllowOverride All* in *apache2.conf* and restart the server, it says *Syntax error on line 38 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
AllowOverride not allowed here*. I will put the whole apache2.conf in my question, please review it. Thanks!

Comment: See my edit - needs to be put in directory tags.

Comment: I had put this in apache2.conf but - no changes, again!